# Visual Studio 2015 I am not able to add plugin from config.xml in cordova application

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

When am trying to add cordova plugin from config.xml file.

its through s error like **Unable to download plugin**. if i am trying from Custom installation using Git then there also it is not allowing me to add plugin it throwing error like **Visual Studio was unable to parse plugin.xml Please ensure plugin.xml exists and contain no error**

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: I have installed both Visual studio 2013 and VS 2015  whether this is creating this problem. because in VS 2013 i have installed cordova tools

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the plugin by modifying config.xml by hand? If so, please try using the config designer to add plugins rather than edit the xml file by hand. The designer will ensure that the xml file is written in the proper format, and it allows you to enter custom plugins through git. Simply double click the config.xml file from the solution explorer and it will open the designer.

[image]

We have also published a help page with the most common known errors and workarounds. Please see this for more information:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-general.md

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for reply , if i am trying through Custom installation then also i am getting this error :  Visual Studio was unable to parse plugin.xml Please ensure plugin.xml exists and contain no error

Comment: It sounds like there is a syntax error in config.xml. You'll need to correct it before you can do anything. If you can't find the syntax error, it might be easier to cut and paste a brand new file into your project and re-add all of your plugins through the config designer.